# Admin menu post type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, admin, sub-menu

Is it possible to get a container post type menu item with all custom post types inside of it?!

1.All post types
1.1 post type 1
1.2 post type 2
1.3 post type 3
1.4 ect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Use function add_menu_page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page to add parent "All post types", then use add_submenu_page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page to add pages to parent page:

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_custom_menu_page' );
    function my_custom_menu_page() {
        $slug = 'all-post';
        add_menu_page( 'All post types', 'All post types', 'edit_posts', $slug, '__return_true' );
        foreach( array( 'post', 'page', 'foo', 'bar' ) as $post_type ) {
            $title = sprintf( 'Post type: %s', $post_type );
            $url = sprintf('/edit.php?post_type=%s', $post_type);
            add_submenu_page( $slug, $title, $title, 'edit_posts', $url );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what i was looking for! :)